# Magento 2 : how to LIbrary import using composer

Tags: admin, extensions, installation, composer, magento2.2.3

How can we library import without composer update give any solution.

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

No, cli command

```
php bin/magento setup: upgrade
```

is used only to upgrade schema/data of internal modules of magento based on increase in version of module or install module in case of new module.

The magento itself is upgraded through composer. It is neccessary to understand that composer updates modules based on `composer.json` located at magento's root directory.

So you should mention dependency of required extension in your `composer.json` and run following command ;

```
 composer update
```

Or running composer require command with name of the module you require as mentioned  in tutorial I have attached.

It would not update magento as the version of the magento modules mentioned in `composer.json` is not changed.

You can follow this tutorial too - https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/install-magento-2-extension-by-composer/